# CEF in AvaloniaUI

Tags: chromium-embedded, avalonia

I am considering Avalonia UI as solution fo our multiplatform app - we need to provide Windows, MacOS (desktop) and tablet (iOS and Android) versions of generally same presentation app. But we need to show HTML content in, co need some CEF browser embeded. I know CEF is possible to link on desktop, but i there hope to have it working on tablets as well? Thank you advance for sharing expirience.

Comment: As an alternative we consider Electron and Cordova/Capacitor way....

Answer (score 2):

There is no CEF available on iOS and Android, they have own system web view components.